# .htaccess rewrites are conflicting / pretty urls

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting, seo, pretty-urls

I have a website where the url looks like this:
**example.com/sample?m=1389&t=name-title**

but I want it to look like this:
**example.com/1389/name-title**

I think two of the rewrites are conflicting. The top one is to remove the .php off of every page and the second one is to make the sample.php more seo friendly. Here's my whole htaccess code. Let me know what I'm doing wrong. I don't want file extensions and I want my page urls to look really nice. Thank you.

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]

# Remove www from any URLs that have them:
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

Options All -Indexes

ErrorDocument 403 http://example.com/tapes.php
ErrorDocument 404 http://example.com/404

## EXPIRES CACHING ##
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 week"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 month"
</IfModule>
## EXPIRES CACHING ##

# compress text, html, javascript, css, xml:
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript

# Or, compress certain file types by extension:
<files *.html>
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
</files>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.html$ /sample?m=$1&t=$2 [L]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use that in your root .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews -Indexes
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# Remove www from any URLs that have them:
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

# remove php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]

# external redirect from actual URL to pretty one
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+sample\?m=([^&]+)&t=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2? [R=301,L,NE]

# internal forward from pretty URL to actual one
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(\d+)/([^/]+)/?$ sample.php?m=$1&t=$2 [L,QSA,NC]

# add php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]

ErrorDocument 403 http://example.com/tapes.php
ErrorDocument 404 http://example.com/404
```

Comment: Good solution +1, you may want to move `www` removal code right at the top

Comment: @anubhava Thanks. I hesitated to do that.

Comment: huh, it work just like the one I wrote. everything works except the pretty url code. it still looks like: http://example.com/sample?m=1389&t=name-title

Comment: Did you try to clear the cache, or with other browser ?

Comment: yeah. it only sort of works. like if I go to the actually pretty url it works: http://mixtapemonkey.com/1389/Dave-East-Black-Rose. but if I got to the regular one it doesn't redirect to the pretty one: http://mixtapemonkey.com/sample?m=1389&t=Dave-East-Black-Rose

Comment: Did you delete `Options All -Indexes` ? and add `-Indexes` in the first.

Comment: I deleted all my code and replaced it with your exactly as is.

Comment: Sorry, It was a rookie mistake. I omitted a `&` in `RewriteCond`

Comment: Perfect. it works! Thank you and don't feel bad about your mistake. I'm a terrible programmer. I couldn't do it without you. thanks again.